# Can I put my inventions here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have 100s of inventions that has been sitting. Rather then letting them die with me can I put them here for review? Maybe someone else could make use of them?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "inventions"? In any case, this is a platform for asking and answering questions, rather than a general-purpose forum, so the answer to your question is very likely no. (However, exactly what you mean by "inventions" could affect what alternate forum I'd suggest, e.g., one particular subreddit or another).

Comment: No. Why would you think this is a place for spruiking your inventions?

Comment: @curiousdannii  I thought maybe here.

Comment: @apsillers Example: High voltage power lines electromagnetic magnetic powered drone for long distant continuous flights have any market value? What could this be useful for?

Comment: @Muze That has absolutely nothing to do with the topic of this site.

Comment: Create a blog and post your inventions there, that would be the best. People searching for high voltage power lines electromagnetic magnetic powered drone for long distant continuous flights will most probably find you matching blog article. Cheers!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have commented, the short answer is "no".

To quote the [Help Center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the scope of the site is:

> Open Source Stack Exchange is a question & answer site about a group of related movements which encourage people to give up some of the rights given to them by copyright law, by using licenses which give others the freedom to use and transform their creative works, and which optionally (by using copyleft/share-alike licenses) ensure that these works will always be made available with the same rights.

Discussing your inventions would not be on-topic here.